# Domain Driven Design best practices recommendation

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have set of data which is either in database or cross boundary service let's say bunch of active products. When I make a query to application there is business rule says I have to check whether it is one of the products in that external service before providing response

I'm thinking fluent validation query validation request and pass in mediator to the validator by dependency injection. This means now I can call the external service with issuing a another query and validate the request before it hits the handler.

Diagram

RequestQueryA ->Validation pipe -> Validator -> mediator with RequesQueryB -> B handler-> B Response-> Validator-> Validation pipe next->A handler-> AResponse

But not sure whether it's a good practice. Please advise

Answer (score 1):

Crossing the boundaries is an infrastructure concern that requires an infrastructure answer, not really a business rule.

What you are doing is cross bounded context query and you have two approaches for doing that:

- CQRS
- API composition

In an API composition architecture, you do not manipulate data from cross boundary service. Add an API gateway in front of both services and have it do the aggregation.

In a CQRS architecture, you need to have an asynchronous communication mechanism between your services, so your current service can receive information from that external bounded context and maintain a local copy. Then your service can return data from both contexts, although only authoritative for what is local.